# Can I find out how much heat in temperature can a resistor give if I know its wire and its resistance value?

Tags: resistors, power-electronics, heat

- Wire :  nichrome 80:20
- Ohms per metre : 750 ohms per metre
- Resistance value : 5k ohms
- Resistors dimensions : 8mm diameter and 50mm.

Voltage I am going to pass is 240v.

How much heat does Resistors dessipate ? (Can I guess the temperature or do we have formula for calculating heat in temperature)

Comment: heat in measured in joules, temperature is measured in kelvin (or some lesser units)  heat is not measured in temperature.

Comment: Hi jasen so as per information given above can we derive how much heat the Resistors will dessipate in joules

Comment: 240^2/5k is about 12 watts. In a resistor 50mm long and 8mm diameter in free air, I would guess it will get too hot to touch (>60C), but not hot enough to desolder itself (<180C). I'd be interested to know what temperature you measure when you do the experiment.

Comment: Joules is simply power * time. To calculate the temperature you'd need to know the rate of cooling which is highly dependent on the resistor's shape and surface area, and its cooling (particularly the airflow around it). That's a complex problem, much easier to measure.

Comment: Hi Neil, after doing experiment I am getting temperature of 80 degree centigrade

Comment: @ Neil , I wanted to lower down temperature but how can I do it ??

Comment: @brian , Resistors share is round tube, with 50mm length and 8mm diameter, 20% free coverage area, and free air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reisitance value: 5k ohms.
>
> Voltage I am going to pass is 240 V.

You are not going to "pass" voltage. You will *apply* the voltage to your load. The result will be that *current* will pass through the load.

> How much heat does resistors dissipate?

The heat will be the electrical power (in watts) consumed by the resistor.

$$ P = VI = I^2R = \frac {V_2}{R} $$

Since you know V and R you can use the last option, \$ P = \frac {V_2}{R} \$.

> Can I guess the temperature or do we have formula for calculating heat in temperature.

The temperature will stabilise at the point where heat losses to the environment or the matter you are heating equals the power input. You will probably have to experiment to find the resultant temperature.

The *energy* you put into the system will be \$ E = P \cdot t \$ and will be in joules (J) or watt-hours (Wh).

Comment: Yes.. that's the only option I m doing right now..

Comment: @MilanUmeshDave you show thanks and appreciation by accepting (ticking) the answer and voting up. Given the quality and effort put into this answer it needs it...